# php - sort multidimensional array based on the dateTime

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, datetime, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 15:00
            [end] => 15:25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 17:00
            [end] => 17:20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 11:15
            [end] => 11:35
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [start] => 10:50
            [end] => 11:20
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [start] => 14:20
            [end] => 14:25
        )
)
```

I want to sort the above array by end time key using [dateTime], the final output should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 10:50
            [end] => 11:20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 11:15
            [end] => 11:35
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 14:20
            [end] => 14:25
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [start] => 15:00
            [end] => 15:25
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [start] => 17:00
            [end] => 17:20
        )
)
```

Can anyone suggest a way to sort/order this based on end time key using [dateTime]

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? Whats your DateTime attempt script?

Comment: Time slots will be generated from users, and i need them to be in correct order when i display them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), create a `DateTime` for both the `['end']` values and compare them in the comparison function.

For example:

```
$arrays = [
    [
        "start" => "15:00",
        "end" => "15:25"
    ],
    [
        "start" => "17:00",
        "end" => "17:20"
    ],
    [
        "start" => "11:15",
        "end" => "11:35"
    ],
    [
        "start" => "10:50",
        "end" => "11:20"
    ],
    [
        "start" => "14:20",
        "end" => "14:25"
    ],
];

usort($arrays, function($a, $b) {
    return new DateTime($a['end']) > new DateTime($b['end']);
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/b3NGq)